# Set View Gone but still take up space

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my Code that is used in RecyleViewAdapater!

```
val yearOfMemory = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(memory.timeOfMemory)
// if year not show before, show it.
if (!yearSet.contains(yearOfMemory)) {
  holder.yearOfMemories.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  holder.yearOfMemories.text = yearOfMemory
  yearSet.add(yearOfMemory)
}
```

Here is my ReccleView XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/month_and_day_of_memory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/content_of_memory"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content_of_memory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/year_of_group_memory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/month_and_day_of_memory"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/month_and_day_of_memory"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Like this, I already have set TextView(@+id/year_of_group_memory) Gone, but it still takes up space at the second item,and it don't take up at the third item.

I have tried all kinds. So, how can I fix it.?

I turn on the layout bounds.

[image]

So,how can cut off the below height,now?

Comment: show your full xml

Comment: show your xml please

Comment: Try `android:visibility="invisible"`

Comment: @SiddharthPatel  `invisible` occupy AREA

Comment: I post full xml

Comment: notify data set changed after changing the visibility

Answer (score 3):

Is your code in a RecyclerView adapter? If so, you must explicitly hide it due to the view recycling mechanism. Always have explicit if-else statements when hiding/showing views.

```
val yearOfMemory = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(memory.timeOfMemory)
if (!yearSet.contains(yearOfMemory)) {
  holder.yearOfMemories.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  holder.yearOfMemories.text = yearOfMemory
  yearSet.add(yearOfMemory)
} else {
  holder.yearOfMemories.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Also try replacing your viewholder contents with the following xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year_of_group_memory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:lines="2"
        tools:text="2017"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month_and_day_of_memory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/year_of_group_memory"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/year_of_group_memory"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="03-11"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_of_memory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/month_and_day_of_memory"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/month_and_day_of_memory"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="第一次接吻"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you use this, you have to set the height of `yearOfMemories` to 0 or `wrap_content` accordingly.

Comment: Kindly check this answer.

Comment: Turn on `Show layout bounds` in developer options in your emulator. Verify that `year_of_group_memory` is indeed being shown when it shouldn't be. If it is, then verify that `yearSet.contains(yearOfMemory)` is logically correct

Comment: yearSet is  HashSet<String>()

Comment: Btw, your data content ;)

Comment: I've added an alternative solution. `ConstraintLayout` might be imposing some constraints that you are not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/year_of_group_memory"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone"/>
```

you hide this `TextView` but youre putting `android:textSize="36sp"` that it shouldn't have and other margins and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf=`

Comment: It doesn't matter if textSize is 36 or 1000 . if the view is set as gone it should be gone